# Unawarded bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I set up a bounty of 50. No one made a good answer, and the only answer available has 0 votes.

The bounty perioid now has expired. Did I simply lost 50 of reputation without getting nothig back?

Question: [Playing MP3 in chunks with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679521/playing-mp3-in-chunks-with-java)

Comment: Yep. Bounties are no guarantees for an answer to your question.

Comment: I believe at least half of reputation should come back

Comment: Nope. You don't get a refund either if you advertise in a newspaper without result. You pay for the extra attention. Not for the end result.

Comment: You got a week where your question appeared on the featured tab - not "nothing back".

Comment: Ah I see your point of view...